# How can I disable all features without losing data created with it?

Tags: features

In my project I've used the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module to deploy content types with its fields and field groups, image styles, views, panels, taxonomies.

The project became very large and the features start to confuse each other.

I would like to disable and delete all features to create new ones for further development and not lose all data.

I tried [Features Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) module but it works just for views, rules and boxes.

**My question**: How can I disable all features without losing data created with it?

Comment: I would love to know this as well. I've had bad luck using FTools, and haven't figured out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.